# how to redraw completely a view after orientation change using auto-layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, autolayout

If I have a view in which there are 6 icons, and in portrait mode each 2 are aligned horizontally, like below

A   B

C   D

E   F

then how can I redraw these after orientation change so that they should look like below in landscape.

A B C

D E F

I am thinking about doing this only through Interface builder, using a XIB. Is it possible or coding by overriding is the only solution ?

Comment: That sounds like a job for `UICollectionView`!

Comment: Then can you provide me a useful link ? I never played with collection view though, but I just started working with auto-layout and thinking about feasibility of doing the above task using auto-layout but unable to think how shall I start working with the landscape orientation.

Comment: @Rameswar is that fixed that u only need to display 6 icons only in both orientation or is that gonna change in future?

Comment: @ArunKumar I am just trying out an example, so in this example yes it is fixed, only 6 icons, if with this scenario it is possible then I may apply it in a real time project where the icons count may vary.

Comment: @Rameswar if that icons count is going to vary you can make use of collection view.  By subclassing uiview you can achieve your current desired design